# How to write a fairly complicated python regular expression for addresses and place names?

Tags: regex

I am trying to compare a business place name and address with that of another that is likely a duplicate. The problem is, the names and addresses are often entered by people manually and so obviously there are various differences.

Here are some examples:

St. vs. St vs. Street

Ste. 14 vs. Ste 14 vs. Suite 14 vs. #14

NE 39th Ave. vs. 39th Ave. vs. 39th Avenue vs. NE 39th Avenue

And quite a few more are possible...

I want to write a regular expression in my program (using python) to compare the names and the addresses that will catch these slight differences. Very often I actually have seen addresses that look exactly the same but for the few that don't, I don't want the regex to completely reject it and say that they aren't the same.

The same can sometimes go for place names. (Real) Examples:

"El Dorado" vs. "Eldorado Mexican Restaurant"

"East Atlanta Coffee Shop" vs. "Joe's East Atlanta Coffee Shop"

"Village Restaurant" vs. "Baba's Village" <----these both had the exact same address and phone number when I checked, so technically they are duplicates

"Djr Cleaning Enterprises" vs. "DJR Cleaning Enterprises Inc"

If you have any suggestions on how to go about doing this or ideas for code, I would appreciate it because I only know how to do simple regex things right now. I've never had this big of a problem before...

Thanks.

Comment: You could use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/streetAddressParser.py) to help parse the street information

Comment: this is not really a Python question

Comment: This is almost certainly beyond regular expressions.  You could use regexes to extract relevant pieces of the strings (e.g., extract street names and address numbers), but you'll need to have other logic to compare them and decide whether they're "the same" or not.

Comment: I do not recommend tackling this kind of a problem with a single regex, or you might end up with a monstrosity like [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone in the comments has mentioned, this problem isn't well suited to a single regex. I've done a heap of work in the same area recently and I'll start by saying that you'll never get it 100% perfect. It's a matter of getting it "as good as possible".

Focussing on the address comparison component, the best strategy that I found is the following:

1. Tokenise the address into individual words (thus ignoring weird punctuation etc.) and re-join the string.
2. From the end, search for a Country or State (from predefined lists) - remove and store if found. We search from the end because the end of an address seems more predictable than the start!
3. From the end, search for a Postcode or Zipcode using `(\d{4})` where 4 is the number of digits - remove and store if found. Replace 4 with your target country's number or digits.
4. From the end, search for a Suburb - remove and store if found. We had a predefined hashmap/dictionary or suburbs which helped a lot. It's also best to store each match for later to help choose the best one (checking post/zip code matches, for example). Perhaps you can also lookup a suburb from the post/zip code if you have that data.
5. Last is to find a street address! Very difficult, since there're so many formats:

   1. I use this to extract the unit/shop/suite/site/factory/lot component:

      `(unit|unt|un|u|shop|shp|suite|ste|se|site|factory|fy|lot|lt)s?(\s|\.)?(\w?\d+\w?)`
   2. I generated an ordinal numbers regex to extract the level/floor with this:

      `((\w??\d+\w??|g|grnd|ground|lower|first|second|third|fourth|fifth|sixth|seventh|eighth|nineth|tenth|eleventh|twelth|1st|2st|3rd|4th|5th|6th|7th)(?:\s*|\.*|\s*)*(level|lvl|l|floor|flr|fl|f)`
   3. Once the other components have been removed, you're often just left with something resembling a street address. I used this to extract it:

      `\d+(\s*-\s?\d*|\s*)?\D+(highway|freeway|alley|arcade|avenue|boulevard|bypass|chase|circle|circlet|circuit|circus|close|court|cove|crescent|drive|esplanade|fairway|garden|gardens|grove|lane|mall|mews|parade|parkway|place|plaza|promenade|quay|ridge|ridgeway|road|row|square|street|terrace|walk|way|Al|ar|ave|blvd|by|cc|ch|ci|cs|cct|cres|cr|cst|dip|dr|ed|ent|es|fry|fo|fmn|fwy|hwy|int|la|lp|mi|mr|pde|pwy|ps|pt|pro|qs|ra|rge|rd|rty|rw|sp|st|tce|tk|trl|tn|vs|wk|wy|cl|ct|cy|ce|cro|dl|el|gp|gns|gl|gm|gr|hts|lkt|me|pl|pa|rt|ri|sh|sq|tp|tr|vl|vw|dv|bvd)\b`

Like a said, it's not a simple process. We were able to get pretty good results with the above algorithm. Once you have parsed two addresses in this way, you can compare components to figure out if they're the same.

Also worth noting how different country use different address formats. Since we're looking at Australian addresses, you may need to modify things a bit. The principles are the same though, I'd imagine.

Hopefully this helps.